# how to get value from returned instance of deferred

Tags: python, mongodb, twisted

I use txmongo lib as the driver for mongoDB.
In its limited docs, the find function in txmongo will return an instance of deferred, but how can I get the actual result (like {"IP":11.12.59.119})?? I tried yield, str() and repr() but does not work.

```
def checkResource(self, resource):
    """ use the message to inquire database
        then set the result to a ip variable
    """
    d = self.units.find({'$and': [{'baseIP':resource},{'status':'free'}]},limit=1,fields={'_id':False,'baseIP':True})
    #Here above, how can I retrieve the result in this deferred instance??
    d.addCallback(self.handleReturnedValue)
    d.addErrback(log.err)
    return d

def handleReturnedValue(self, returned):
    for ip in returned:
        if ip is not None:
            d = self.updateData(ip,'busy')
            return d
        else:
            return "NA"
```

Comment: You have to use a callback so value is accessible in handleReturnedValue https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.0.0/core/howto/defer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write asynchronous code in twisted looking more like synchronous, try using `defer.inlineCallbacks`

This is from the docs:
http://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/twisted-16.2.0/core/howto/defer-intro.html#inline-callbacks-using-yield

> Consider the following function written in the traditional Deferred
> style:

```
def getUsers():
   d = makeRequest("GET", "/users")
   d.addCallback(json.loads)
   return d
```

> using inlineCallbacks, we can write this as:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue

@inlineCallbacks
def getUsers(self):
    responseBody = yield makeRequest("GET", "/users")
    returnValue(json.loads(responseBody))
```

EDIT:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue

@inlineCallbacks
def checkResource(self, resource):
    """ use the message to inquire database
        then set the result to a ip variable
    """
    returned = yield self.units.find({'$and': [{'baseIP':resource},{'status':'free'}]},limit=1,fields={'_id':False,'baseIP':True})
    # replacing callback function
    for ip in returned:
        if ip is not None:
            d = self.updateData(ip,'busy') # if this returns deferred use yield again
            returnValue(d)            
    returnValue("NA")
```

Comment: If I make it a generator, then the program don't even go into this checkResource function at all

Comment: Have you set decorator on function?

Comment: No. Now I try again after I add it, it seems that I get a list object, which seems to be the right type at least. However, how do I change the function..? Because it was supposed to return a deferred instance, and now it returns an other object?

Comment: Use `returnValue` and this decorator makes it return deferred with supplied data. To sum up it still returns deferred.

Comment: Ok. But I don't understand in what cases I need this. In the official example of TxMongo, they use this decorator method only when using find(), not other functions including insert(), update().. so when a function returns a value, I need a decorator style function??

Comment: If you want to get returned value from function returning deferred. This just makes it easier to program, no need to fight with callbacks. Decorator takes care of them for you.

Comment: Thx. In addition, I have 2 statements: `d.addCallback(self.handleReturnedValue)
    d.addErrback(log.err)` . So how do I do with these callback functions? just refactor them to `self.handleReturnedValue(d)`..?

Comment: Check edit. Watch out for `self.updateData` if it returns deferred (see code comment).

Comment: If I return deferred instance (without using decorator), this instance will still include the returned value, right? In the official instruction, they say "deferred instance is like a placeholder" and this statement: `d.addCallback(self.dispatch)` will pass the value in `d` to `self.dispatch` right?

Comment: Yes, but then pass along to another callback in chain returned value from self.dispatch

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the actual value from the deferred, you can, after the result becomes available. How long it takes to become available depends on what it is waiting on.

Take a look at the example below. There's an arbitrary 2 second delay before the result becomes available, so attempting to access it before then throws an `AttributeError`

```py
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor


def getDummyData(inputData):
    """
    This function is a dummy which simulates a delayed result and
    returns a Deferred which will fire with that result. Don't try too
    hard to understand this.

    From Twisted docs
    """
    deferred = defer.Deferred()
    # simulate a delayed result by asking the reactor to fire the
    # Deferred in 2 seconds time with the result inputData * 3
    reactor.callLater(2, deferred.callback, inputData * 3)
    return deferred


d = getDummyData(2)

reactor.callLater(1, lambda: print(d))
# Prints: <Deferred at 0x7f4853ed3550>

reactor.callLater(3, lambda: print(d))
# Prints: <Deferred at 0x7f4853ed3550 current result: 6>

reactor.callLater(3, lambda: print(d.result))
# Prints: 6

# Throws AttributeError because Deferred does not have a result after 1 sec
# reactor.callLater(1, lambda: print(d.result))

reactor.callLater(4, reactor.stop)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Nope.  Don't use the `result` attribute of `Deferred`.  It might look like it works sometimes but it isn't reliable.  It's basically an implementation detail.  It should have been `_result`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that is the case? Obviously you can't access the result of the function hasn't returned yet, but otherwise I can't see how this would be unreliable. How else can you access the actual result instead of the deferred object?

Comment: It's easier to explain if I can write some code, which is hard to do in a comment.  Seems like there should be some existing SO question about this but if you can't find one, open a new one and I'll answer it. :)

Comment: Appreciate it. I think the question is actually the one I've replied to. Maybe you can respond with an answer here? The original poster is asking how to get a strong out of the deferred object, which is what prompted my reply. Interested to see what the best solution is.

Comment: The accepted answer is more or less correct.  The question you're asking is why it's *wrong* to use the result attribute. :)

Comment: I asked in a new question. Looking forward to your insight. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56995661/8213783