# Why is it wrong to use Deferred.result to get the result of a Twisted Deferred object?

Tags: python, twisted

From what I've read, one should never use the `result` attribute of a Twisted `Deferred` object to access the value of the Deferred. I suspect the reasoning for this is that either

1. No result may not be available at the time of access (raises
   `AttributeError`)
2. The result may not be final at the time of access (i.e. not all
       callbacks have run)

Is there ever a situation where it is appropriate to access the value of the result of the Deferred? Is there a better way to access the result to assign it to a variable or use it later without adding additional callbacks to the Deferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicions are essentially correct.

> No result may not be available at the time of access (raises AttributeError)

The idea of `Deferred` is that some work is happening and it won't be finished by some fixed time.  It will be finished when it is finished.  Fortunately, when it is finished, `Deferred` can tell you about the result - this is what callbacks are for.  This means that, *without* using callbacks, you can't know when the work is finished.  You might check too early and get an `AttributeError` (or failure of another sort, more on this below).  You might check too late and have wasted some time.  You can "fix" the too-early case by checking repeatedly and handling the error.  This is called "polling".  Large parts of Twisted exist to remove the need to perform polling because polling is typically undesirable (it's expensive).  The only way to "fix" the too-late case is by checking more frequently - which makes the "too-early" case worse.

> The result may not be final at the time of access (i.e. not all callbacks have run)

A feature `Deferred` offers is that it allows for *composition* in event-driven programming.  You can have unit A which performs some task and returns a `Deferred`.  You can have unit B which performs some task and depends on unit A and returns some other `Deferred`.  Such composition *could* look like this:

```
d = Deferred()

d_a = unit_a()
def a_finished(result):
    d_b = unit_b(result)
    d_b.addCallback(d_final.callback)
d_a.addCallback(a_finished)
```

What values does `d.result` take on over the course of the execution of this example?  First it is an `AttributeError` and then it is whatever value the `unit_b` `Deferred` is called back with.  In this case, you have no incomplete or intermediate results being exposed and there's no problem.  However, this composition is awkward, verbose, and failure-prone (it misses error propagation and cancellation features, for example).

The easy, idiomatic, encouraged way to compose `Deferred` APIs is:

```
d = unit_a()
d.addCallback(unit_b)
```

Easier to write, easier to read, and you get features like railroad-style error propagation.

What values does `d.result` take on in this case, though?  First it is an `AttributeError`.  Then, after `unit_a` is done, `d.result` is the `Deferred` returned by `unit_b`.  So if you look it up here, not only do you not have the final result but you don't even have a real value, you have a `Deferred` instead.  Only after `unit_b` is done does `d` take on the real result of `unit_b`.

There are other possible sequences as well.  They arise from other `Deferred` usage patterns that aren't as preferred as the one above but they are certainly possible.  For example, you might have an implementation which does:

```
d = unit_a()
```

and then have `d` exposed to your code.  After that point you might have the implementation proceed to:

```
d.addCallback(unit_b)
```

Now `d.result` proceeds from `AttributeError` to the result of `unit_a` to a `Deferred` to the result of `unit_b`.  The above is not excellent use of `Deferred` but as you can see, it is entirely possible.  If you are polling `d.result` in this case, you have the complication of having to guess whether a non-`Deferred` value is the result of `unit_a` or of `unit_b`.

> Is there ever a situation where it is appropriate to access the value of the result of the Deferred?

It's hard to completely rule it out.  Certainly in the test suite for `Deferred` itself there are some direct accesses and these may be legitimate.  It's possible that in some other test-related tools it may be appropriate to access the `result` attribute this way - but ideally even there it would be avoided or testing libraries (such as Twisted's trial) would provide better tools for writing these kinds of tests (eg trial does provide `successResultOf`, `failureResultOf`, and `assertNoResult`).  Beyond those cases, I think you should look very, very carefully at any use of the `result` attribute and you will probably find that there is a better (more maintainable, less fragile) solution using callbacks.

> Is there a better way to access the result to assign it to a variable or use it later without adding additional callbacks to the Deferred?

The better way to access the result is always to add an additional callback.  As another answer suggests, `inlineCallbacks` is a way to use callbacks that doesn't *look* like using callbacks and is preferred by many.  It lets you do a simple assignment to a local to retrieve a result but the implementation is still using `Deferred.addCallback` and the related APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for. With inlinecallbacks you are able to access the result without the need of writing callbacks.

`@inlineCallBacks
def thingummy():
    thing = yield makeSomeRequestResultingInDeferred()
    print(thing)  # the result! hoorj!`

https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.inlineCallbacks.html

Comment: The question is really about why it is incorrect or bad practice to access the result attribute directly. In your example we don't need to attach callbacks to the deferred, but what if `thingummy` returns a deferred? How do you get the result from that without using the result attribute?